# websocket client in core php

Tags: php, websocket

I am trying to send data to PHP websocket server, although it sends the data but the data received is a garbage values. How can fix this to get correct values posted to websocket php server?

Below is my websocket php client script

```
<?php
$host = 'example.com:9000/server.php';  //where is the websocket server
$port = 9000; //ssl
$local = "http://localhost/";  //url where this script run
$data = json_encode(array("server_msg"=> "1","device_id"=> "DDD-123455678"));  //data to be send

$head = "GET / HTTP/1.1"."\r\n".
    "Host: $host"."\r\n".
    "Upgrade: websocket"."\r\n".
    "Connection: Upgrade"."\r\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Key: asdasdaas76da7sd6asd6as7d"."\r\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13"."\r\n".
    "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n"."\r\n";
////WebSocket handshake
$sock = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2);
fwrite($sock, $head ) or die('error:'.$errno.':'.$errstr);
$headers = fread($sock, 2000);
fwrite($sock, "\x00$data\xff" ) or die('error:'.$errno.':'.$errstr);
$wsdata = fread($sock, 2000);  //receives the data included in the websocket package "\x00DATA\xff"
$retdata = trim($wsdata,"\x00\xff"); //extracts data
////WebSocket handshake
fclose($sock);

echo $retdata;
?>
```

Thanks

Hi,

I have already tried it and it gives me error as below:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'WebSocket\ConnectionException' with message 'Connection to 'ws://************/server.php' in /var/www/webclientphp/vendor/textalk/websocket/lib/Client.php on line 149

WebSocket\ConnectionException: Connection to 'ws://************/server.php' failed: Server sent invalid upgrade response: HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake Upgrade: websocket Connection: Upgrade WebSocket-Origin: ************ WebSocket-Location: ws://************:9000/demo/shout.php Sec-WebSocket-Accept:Kfh9QIsMVZcl6xEPYxPHzW8SZ8w= in /var/www/webclientphp/vendor/textalk/websocket/lib/Client.php on line 149

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Your data needs to be encoded to match the [Websocket protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) (frames, headers, encryption etc).

The server will be expecting websocket frames, and will try to decode them as per the protocol, so you can't just send raw data. It will also send data to you in this format.

The easiest way is to use a library, like [this one](https://github.com/Textalk/websocket-php)

Comment: Hi, 

I have already tried it and it gives me error. Please see the actual edited question for error details.

Comment: That sounds like the server is incompatible with the client, possibly using an outdated protocol. What is the server? Do you have any code or control over it?